# Flutter Firebase How To Do Dynamic Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have query like this;

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

var sRef = _firestore
          .collection("vehicles")
          .where("models.car", isEqualTo: "true")
          .where("models.plane", isEqualTo: "true")
          .where("models.motor", isEqualTo: "true");
```

With this query I can query which list include car,plane and motor at the same time. But I want to do query dynamiclly. Therefore I did this for loop;

```
List<String> item = ["car", "motor", "plane"];

   var sRef;
    
   for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
          
            sRef = _firestore
                          .collection("vehicles").where("models.${item[i]}", isEqualTo: "true");
                          
        }
```

But it didn't work as I expected.

When I want to use the for loop to display the lists containing the elements in the item list, the code additionally shows me the lists containing the last element in the item list.

For example, in this example, it shows me the lists that include car, motor and plane, and it also shows lists that contain only plane, but I don't want to display only the lists that contain plane, I just want to display the lists that contain car, motor, plane.

And after I tried this for loop;

```
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  if (sRef == null) {
    sRef = _firestore.collection("vehicles").where("models.${item[i]}", isEqualTo: "true");  
  } else {
    sRef.where("models.${item[i]}", isEqualTo: "true");  
  }  
}
```

But this time this for loop code additionally shows me the lists containing the first element in the item list.

For example, in this example, it shows me the lists that include car, motor and plane, and it also shows lists that contain only car, but I don't want to display only the lists that contain car, I just want to display the lists that contain car, motor, plane.

Why I get list named PLANE with list named ALL when I use the first loop or why I get list named CAR with list named ALL when I use second for loop. I just want get to list named ALL.

Unlike the 2 methods, there must be a way to make this query dynamic somehow. Flutter can't be such an incomplete language, I've searched in many places, I tried many solutions, but I couldn't find a solution for this, is there really a way to do this in the world.

These are my Firebase Documents for better understanding of my database;

[Car List Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkZhL.png)

[Plane List Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYVWD.png)

[Motor List Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7ux9.png)

[All List Document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coVyI.png)

Comment: Try `"models.${item[i]}"`. Now the output should be `models.car` and so on. Example on [DartPad](https://prnt.sc/1h27k5m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small mistake in the answer to your previous question. To add conditions to the exiting query, use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  if (sRef == null) {
    sRef = _firestore.collection("vehicles").where("models.${item[i]}", isEqualTo: "true");  
  } else {
    sRef = sRef.where("models.${item[i]}", isEqualTo: "true");  
    //  this is new
  }  
}
```

---

I actually prefer this version below myself, as it keeps the `if` condition out of the loop:

```
sRef = _firestore.collection("vehicles");
for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
  sRef = sRef.where("models.${item[i]}", isEqualTo: "true");  
}
```

The result between the two snippets is the same, I just find the second version easier to maintain.

Comment: Thank you so muchhh I've been dealing with this problem for about a month.